# How to set recordsTotal on datatable with jquery wihtout server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to setting recordTotal on my function. The function i using for daterange.

```
table = $("#id").DataTable({
   columns: [
     { title : "Tes" },
     .................
   ]
})
function cb(start, end){
   axios.get(url, {
       headers {...}, params: {...} 
   }).then(function(res){
     var dataset [];
     var results = res.data.results;
     for( var i =0; i < results.length; i++){
        dataset.append([
           results.1,
           results.2,
           ..........
        ])

     }
     table.clear();
     table.rows.add(dataset);
     table.draw();
   })
}
```

I need set value for recordsTotal before draw.

Comment: have you tried this one? https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Comment: no, i need to set for recordsTotal ( Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries ), i need set for value 57, not sum my data.

Comment: i didn't understand, do you have a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: you can look on [here](https://ibb.co/fTVyfw) i need to set that with jquery.

Comment: i didn't quite understand why you want to have the total when it is already given by datatables here: "Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries"

Comment: i need set that because not use server side ajax request

Comment: even if you are not using server side ajax request it will show `rowTotal`